# How to send MIME (Multipart Media Encapsulation) content type message using erlang HTTP method?

Tags: http, erlang, multipart, cowboy, mimemultipart

I'm currently working on a module in Erlang that sends an HTTP POST request with a multipart/related message containing both JSON and binary data. However, I'm facing issues with concatenating the JSON message and binary data correctly.

```
-module(MIME_post).
-export([send_post_request/0, get_modify_req/0]).

send_post_request() ->
    % ... (existing code)

    Url = "http://localhost:8666",

    JsonData = #{<<"some_val">> => <<"imsi-460886666660006">>},
    JsonBody = jsx:encode(JsonData),

    Headers = [{"Content-Type", "multipart/related;boundary=-21ba7406cff5fa6c192d6b78fe58e16c5fd0cde4111e10f11c2bf55b45a5"}],

    MimeBinary = <<"2e0a00d1">>,
    Request = {Url, Headers, "multipart/related", JsonBody}, 

%here i want to include that MIME binary the Json body should get recognised as json and MIME binary should get recognized as another content type 

    case httpc:request(post, Request, [stream], []) of
        {ok, {{_, 201, _}, _Headers, ResponseBody}} ->
            io:format("HTTP Response Header:~p~n", [Headers]),
            io:format("HTTP Response: ~s~n", [ResponseBody]),
            {ok, ResponseBody};
        {error, Reason} ->
            io:format("HTTP Request failed with reason: ~p~n", [Reason]),
            {error, Reason}
    end.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
           request(Method, Request, HttpOptions, Options)  
case httpc:request(post,   Request, [stream],    []     ) of
```

`stream` is not one of the available [HttpOptions](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/httpc#request-5):

```
HttpOption = 
    {timeout, timeout()} |
    {connect_timeout, timeout()} |
    {ssl, [ssl:tls_option()]} |
    {autoredirect, boolean()} |
    {proxy_auth, {string(), string()}} |
    {version, HttpVersion} |
    {relaxed, boolean()}
```

Rather `stream` is one of the allowed `Options` for the fourth argument to `httpc:request/4`, and it should be in a 2-tuple along with a value.

In your `Content-Type` header, you probably want to change:

```
-21ba....
```

to:

```
21ba...
```

Also, add:

```
;type=\"application/json\"
```

to the end.  [Required](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2387).

You may also need to specify a `Content-Length` header that specifies the number of bytes in the body.

This is what you want the body of the request to look like:

```
--21ba7406cff5fa6c192d6b78fe58e16c5fd0cde4111e10f11c2bf55b45a5
Content-Type: application/json

{"some_key":"imsi-460886666660006"}
--21ba7406cff5fa6c192d6b78fe58e16c5fd0cde4111e10f11c2bf55b45a5
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

2e0a00d1
--21ba7406cff5fa6c192d6b78fe58e16c5fd0cde4111e10f11c2bf55b45a5--
```

Note the trailing "--" on the last boundary.  You will have to assemble all that by hand.

The actual boundary that appears in the body of the request is made up of the following parts:

1. An initial Carriage Return + Line Feed, which is referred to as `CRLF`, and consists of the characters "\r\n" (which is two octets).  Omit the initial CRLF for the first boundary in the body.
2. The two characters "--".
3. The boundary specified in the Content-Type header.
4. A terminating CRLF, or if it's the last boundary, then a terminating "--".

See [RFC 2406, Section 5.1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046.html#section-5.1.1) and [RFC 822, Section 3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822#section-3.2).

Probably the easiest way to assemble the body is using an `iolist`, which is a list that contains the integers 0..255 or binaries or ascii-strings (or sublists containing any of those types).  Here, the useful trait of an iolist is that erlang automatically concatenates everything together.  Below, the code uses a list of strings to take advantage of that concatenation effect:

```
send_post_request() ->
    % ... (existing code)

    Url = "http://localhost:8080/print_request",

    JsonData = #{<<"some_key">> => <<"imsi-460886666660006">>},
    JsonBody = jsx:encode(JsonData),

    MimeBinary = <<"2e0a00d1">>,

    Boundary = "21ba7406cff5fa6c192d6b78fe58e16c5fd0cde4111e10f11c2bf55b45a5",
    CRLF = "\r\n",

    ContentTypeHeader = [   % this is an iolist() 
        "multipart/related; ",
        "boundary=", Boundary, 
        "; type=\"application/json\""
    ], 
    
    RequestBody = [  % this is an iolist()
        "--", Boundary, CRLF,
        "Content-Type: application/json", CRLF, CRLF,
        JsonBody,
        CRLF, "--", Boundary, CRLF,
        "Content-Type: application/octet-stream", CRLF, CRLF,
        MimeBinary, 
        CRLF, "--", Boundary, "--"
    ],

    BodyBinary = iolist_to_binary(RequestBody),
    ContentLength = byte_size(BodyBinary),

    AdditionalHeaders = [
        {
            "Content-Length", 
            integer_to_list(ContentLength)
        } 
    ],

    Request = {Url, AdditionalHeaders, ContentTypeHeader, BodyBinary}, 

    Response = httpc:request(post, Request, [], []),
    io:format("Response:~n~p~n", [Response]).
```

Using this express server (https://www.derpturkey.com/node-multipart-form-data-explained/):

```
let express = require('express');
let app     = express();
const port = 8080;

app.post('/print_request', (req, res) => {

  // output the headers
  console.log(req.headers);

 // capture the encoded form data
 req.on('data', (data) => {
   console.log(data.toString());
});

  // send a response when finished reading
  // the encoded form data
  req.on('end', () => {
    res.send('ok');
  });
});

// start server on port 8080
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`)
});
```

...this is the output I see in the server window:

```
Listening on port 8080
{
  'content-type': 'multipart/related; boundary=21ba7406cff5fa6c192d6b78fe58e16c5fd0cde4111e10f11c2bf55b45a5; type="application/json"',
  'content-length': '315',
  te: '',
  host: 'localhost:8080',
  connection: 'keep-alive'
}
--21ba7406cff5fa6c192d6b78fe58e16c5fd0cde4111e10f11c2bf55b45a5
Content-Type: application/json

{"some_key":"imsi-460886666660006"}
--21ba7406cff5fa6c192d6b78fe58e16c5fd0cde4111e10f11c2bf55b45a5
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

2e0a00d1
--21ba7406cff5fa6c192d6b78fe58e16c5fd0cde4111e10f11c2bf55b45a5--
```

Here's the output in the erlang shell:

```
1> my_http:send_post_request().
Response:
{ok,{{"HTTP/1.1",200,"OK"},
     [{"connection","keep-alive"},
      {"date","Sun, 21 Jan 2024 02:19:35 GMT"},
      {"etag","W/\"2-eoX0dku9ba8cNUXvu/DyeabcC+s\""},
      {"content-length","2"},
      {"content-type","text/html; charset=utf-8"},
      {"x-powered-by","Express"},
      {"keep-alive","timeout=5"}],
     "ok"}}
ok
```

Good luck.  Are you sure your server knows how to parse the request body?  If not, you probably want to use a Content-Type of `multipart/form-data`, with a `Content-Type` header like this:

```
"multipart/form-data;boundary=21ba7406cff5fa6c192d6b78fe58e16c5fd0cde4111e10f11c2bf55b45a5"
```

And the body of the request will need to look something like this:

```
--21ba7406cff5fa6c192d6b78fe58e16c5fd0cde4111e10f11c2bf55b45a5
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="my_json"
Content-Type: application/json  <followed by two newlines>

<JSON HERE>
--21ba7406cff5fa6c192d6b78fe58e16c5fd0cde4111e10f11c2bf55b45a5
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="my_binary_data"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream <followed by two newlines>

<BINARY DATA HERE>
--21ba7406cff5fa6c192d6b78fe58e16c5fd0cde4111e10f11c2bf55b45a5--
```

A typical server will place the json in `params["my_json"]` and the binary data in `params["my_binary_data"]`.

If your binary data was a jpeg file, you might have a section like this:

```
--21ba7406cff5fa6c192d6b78fe58e16c5fd0cde4111e10f11c2bf55b45a5
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="my_image"; filename="red_square.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

r"?>��Adobed����''2&&2.&&&&.>55555>DAAAAAADDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD  &&6& &6D6++6DDDB5BDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD�}�"��a    !S1A�r��5���
                                                                            ?����-4�f�fbb��a������� �|�G��>v��\��:>��f��)[�֍��6��P�n��yo�� 3��-�C�������#|�@I>�W�������_'�ol���Z�:�_&+ֻ/�Ԙ����
--21ba7406cff5fa6c192d6b78fe58e16c5fd0cde4111e10f11c2bf55b45a5
```

**Response to comment =====**:

In your handler for your route, look for a `multipart` request:

```
-module(hello_handler).
-behavior(cowboy_handler).

-export([init/2, get_json_part/1]).

init(Req, State) ->

    case cowboy_req:parse_header(<<"content-type">>, Req) of
        {<<"multipart">>, <<"related">>, _} ->
            io:format("Found multipart request~n"),
            get_json_part(Req);
        _ ->
            io:format("do something else for requests that aren't multipart~n")
    end,


    NewReq = cowboy_req:reply(200,
        #{<<"content-type">> => <<"text/plain">>},
        <<"Hello Erlang">>,
        Req),

    {ok, NewReq, State}.
```

Then process the multipart request with `get_json_part(Req)`:

```
get_json_part(Req) ->

    case cowboy_req:read_part(Req) of
        {ok, Header=#{<<"content-type">> := <<"application/json">>}, Req1} ->
            {ok, Body, _Req2} = cowboy_req:read_part_body(Req1),
            io:format("Header: ~p~n", [Header]),
            io:format("Body: ~p~n", [Body]);
        {ok, _, Req1} ->
            get_json_part(Req1);
        {done, _Req1} ->
            io:format("json part not found")
    end.
```

This expression:

```
Header=#{<<"content-type">> := <<"application/json">>}
```

matches against a Content-Type header in one of the parts of the multipart request returned by `cowboy_req:read_part(Req)`. This part:

```
#{<<"content-type">> := <<"application/json">>}
```

is a map, and to match it against another map, instead of the normal `=>` that you see between a key and a value in a map:

```
#{<<"content-type">> => <<"application/json">>}
```

you have to use `:=`.  You can also match just part of a map: you don't have to match the whole map.  So any map that contains the key-value pair:

```
<<"content-type">> => <<"application/json">>
```

will match the following:

```
#{<<"content-type">> := <<"application/json">>}
```

The matching map is then assigned to the variable `Header`, so that the matching map can be used later in the function:

```
Header=#{<<"content-type">> := <<"application/json">>}
```

Here's a simpler example doing the same thing:

```
1> Map = #{x => 1, y =>2}.
#{y => 2,x => 1}

2> Result =    #{x := 1} = Map.
#{y => 2,x => 1}

3> Result.
#{y => 2,x => 1}
```